# How do I get the current path of the file executing the current thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

In python, I can do this to get the current file's path:

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

But if I run this on a thread say:

```
def do_stuff():
   class RunThread(threading.Thread):
       def run(self):
           print os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
   a = RunThread()
   a.start()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "readrss.py", line 137, in run
    print os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
NameError: global name '__file__' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import inspect
print(inspect.stack()[0][1])
```

[inspect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html)

Comment: Is it possible to get the absolute path?

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat in inspect docs i do not find absolute path mentioning  I know only can check with os.path.isabs if it is or not ....

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat what if you do dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
absolutepath = os.path.join(dir, relative_path)

Answer (score -1):

I apologise for my previous answer. I was half asleep and replied stupidly.
Every time I've done what you're trying to do, I have used it in the inverse order. E.g. `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`